# Margin between two ablosute -ley positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I have two abslolute -ley positioned containers like so...

HTML

```
<div class=title_container>
   <div class=title>Variable length title</div>
   <div class=title_bg></div>
</div>

<div class=description_container>
   <div class=description>Also variable length description</div>
   <div class=description_bg></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.title_container {
  position:absolute
}
  .title {
    position:relative; z-index:1;
    color:#FFF;
  }
  .title_bg {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    background:#0000FF;
    opacity:0.50;
    width:100%; height:100%;
  }

.description_container {
  position:absolute
}
  .description {
    position:relative; z-index:1;
    color:#FFF;
  }
  .description_bg {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    background:#0000FF;
    opacity:0.50;
    width:100%; height:100%;
  }
```

In order to match transparent background width and heigh with variable lenght text, both containers must be set to absolute position.

Now I need to set margin between two containes, but I can't just set top parameter of containers becase text length can vary, which means if text will be longer than one row, transparent backgrounds will overlap.

How do I set fixed, 20px margin between two containers in this situation?

http://jsbin.com/IyUZUg/2/

Comment: Is it mandatory to keep the divs position:absolute? This behavior is ideal for position:relative.

Comment: I thought that it's mandatory, because I could not match the width of the background to length of the title, if you do cotainer relative, then child would expand parent container to 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I actually can use position relative in this case, but with use of inline-block trick.

HTML

```
<div class=title_container>       
    <div class=title>
        Variable length title 
        Variable length title Variable length title 
        Variable length title Variable length title 
        Variable length title Variable length title 
        Variable length title Variable length title
    </div>
    <div class=title_bg></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class=description_container>
    <div class=description>Also variable length description</div>
    <div class=description_bg></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.title_container {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
  .title {
    position:relative; z-index:1;
    color:#FFF;
    max-width:200px;
  }
  .title_bg {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    background:#0000FF;
    opacity:0.50;
    width:100%; height:100%;
  }

.description_container {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
  .description {
    position:relative; z-index:1;
    color:#FFF;
  }
  .description_bg {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    background:#0000FF;
    opacity:0.50;
    width:100%; height:100%;
  }
```

http://jsbin.com/IyUZUg/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper around both containers that are set to absolute positions.  Then you can control your absolute position via the wrapper.  Containers would then be floated (if desired) to be stacked side by side.  If you want it on top of each other, remove the float.

```
    <div id="contentwrapper">
<div class=title_container>
   <div class=title>Variable length title</div>
   <div class=title_bg></div>
</div>

<div class=description_container>
   <div class=description>Also variable length description</div>
   <div class=description_bg></div>
</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#contentwrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.title_container, .description_container{
    float: left;
}


.title_container{
   padding-right: 20px;
}
  .title {
    position:relative; z-index:1;
    color:#FFF;
  }
  .title_bg {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    background:#0000FF;
    opacity:0.50;
    width:100%; height:100%;
  }


  .description {
    position:relative; z-index:1;
    color:#FFF;
  }
  .description_bg {
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    background:#0000FF; 
    opacity:0.50;
    width:100%; height:100%;
  }
```

## Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hn2HY/9/

Comment: This is not what need rally, I want two elements with two separate backgrounds and in between them to have static margin, let's say 20px white space

Comment: I want to achieve that look http://jsbin.com/ItawIQa/1/edit and when there is long title, the top container should push down the bottom container